# maven The expression ${name} is deprecated. Please use ${project.name} instead

Tags: java, maven

Having some issues detecting the source of this error message and its resolution, sorry hard to share the pom as its something from the company

`The expression ${name} is deprecated. Please use ${project.name} instead. It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build. For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.`

Comment: Somewhere in your pom's or in partens the expression is being used which is long time deprecated and should be replaced...the question is why it's being used anyway...

Comment: The question is more what kind of expression is used... no clue which expression, which xml tag am I looking for? @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0):

Into the maven-jar-plugin I had that issue, changed

```
<Service-Component>${name}</Service-Component>
```

to

```
<Service-Component>${project.name}</Service-Component>
```

For a bit more context

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java,**/*Test.class,**/*TestCase.class,**/.keep</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <version>my-project-name-${project.version}</version>
                        <Service-Component>${project.name}</Service-Component>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```